# Начать работу верстальщика

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, что нужно знать, для того чтобы начать работать (заработать на хлеб) верстальщиком?
1) Имеется ввиду, какие технологии и тому подобное. 
2) Примеры страничек, которые нужно уметь делать начинающему.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы заработать версткой нужны платящие клиенты. А технологии и типичные странички и прочее только помогают вам найти таких клиентов, но самое парадоксальное, что клиента не интересует совершенно как вы решите его задачу, а только факт того, что задача решена и желательно 1) быстро, а лучше "вчера" 2) дешево, а лучше "бесплатно".